# Getting all images from fire storage (Same folder) - Ionic 4

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m using Ionic v4, so i’m trying to get all the images from firebase storage i just didn’t find a way how to get them all.

I’m trying to get them from a folder called ‘images’ and display them.

```
getImage(){
    firebase.storage().ref().child("/images/").getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) =>
            this.image = url;
        )
        .catch(error =>
            console.log('error:', error);
        );
  }
```

I can't get the folder url but i want to get all the images inside it, thanks in advance.